# Responsive Popup Window

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, magnific-popup

I'm using [Magnific Popups](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) ajax popup to to create a popup experience somewhat like Instagram (image on the left, comments on the right, etc). I'm trying to figure out how to make the left and right content box always the same height. If the image on the right is too large it will just fit the div accordingly because it should be responsive. Also, if the entire browser were to become smaller (on a mobile device maybe) the image would appear on top and the content on the bottom.

The image and content are floated as such:

```
.image_container, .content {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

And the float is just cleared with the screen size is reduced using media queries.

I've made a jsfiddle to help understand what I'm trying to explain:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/2/)**

If you click 'open' and resize the iframe you'll see the effect I'm lookng for.

So how would the view container have a set size and the left and right content areas always be the same height? Just simply looking at the example you can see that it looks a little funny.

**EDIT**

I've also tried centering the image vertically and that seems to be a challenge too. I've tried making the css display a table cell then trying `vertical-align: middle` but that didn't end up working.

The solution should work on all modern browsers.

Comment: Can't focus on problem. Kitty and puppy are too cute.

Comment: just put both containers in another div with with background and make the right inner container (with text) transparent! that will simply solves your problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for some like this?
[http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/](http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/43/)

Consider the following function:

```
// Handles the resize event
$(window)
    .off(".resizeImage")
    .on("resize.resizeImage", fnResizeImage);

// Resizes the content2 to fit with image height
function fnResizeImage (e) {
    var imgHeight = $('div.image_container > img').outerHeight(true);
    var cnt1Height = $('div.content > div.content1').outerHeight(true);
    var cnt2 = $('div.content > div.content2').outerHeight(imgHeight - cnt1Height);
}
```

Also is recommended take a look at the plugin documentation: [Magnific-popup API](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api)

Comment: You can also manage the width in the same way, just modify the function `fn_resizeImage()` with `selector.width()` or `selector.outerWidth(true)` functions. Have fun! :)

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Is there a way to do this with just css?

Answer (score 5):

As you asked the vertical alignment. I think you may need something that works like those.

1. http://jsfiddle.net/twksos/NXZxh/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/twksos/NfeQN/

I checked on firefox, chrome and safari. There are still some issues.

- in chrome and safari, you need to refresh to see the responsive but not just resize. (It's interesting and I'm looking at it.)
- in safari, the max-width for #small-dialog stop working.

And the core part should be

```
.image_container, .content {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #3D6AA2;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 638px) {
    .image_container, .content {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
#small-dialog {
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;/*newly added*/
    table-layout: fixed;/*newly added*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. That being said, this was an extra I was looking for. It isn't the main issue. So how would the view container have a set size and the left and right content areas always be the same height?

Answer (score 1):

It is (sort-of) possible with raw CSS, but you have to alter the structure of the html. If you don't use float, the image and every parent element have the height of the image + extra height from other elements and +/- margin's and paddings. It is possible to display an element outside their parent element by using margin. I use this to colour the parent element of the image, then move the image out of that parent element to get the look you wanted.

That said the solution I made is somewhat messy and I doubt it works if the comments exceed the height of the image. I have no clue in what browsers this is displayed 'correctly' (I am forced to use IE9 here and I haven't spend much time properly aligning things). Hopefully it will give you some idea what you could do. I think in this case a little bit of jQuery is maybe more appropiate.

[The 'working' example](http://jsbin.com/uxapew/1/) and [the code to generate it](http://jsbin.com/uxapew/1/edit).

---

On an other note: Although tables are somewhat inconsistent across browsers, this might be an appropiate place to use them.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that when the window size becomes smaller than x a special media css declaration will be applied to your image container (check yourself with any element-inspector)

```
INLINE:57 @media (min-width:1px) and (max-width: 638px)

.image_container, .content {
width: auto;
float: none;
clear: both;
}
```

that removes the 50% width and float  and your desired effect,

just remove that part and it works as you desire

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 3 methods for solving kitty and puppy problem with content, you can check it below:

**but i think if you really sensitive about height or width, the better way is set height & width absolutely with Javascript.**

1. Using Javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/11/

1. Using CSS Method 1:

using `height:100vh` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/9/

more example for understanding **vh**:

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/1/

1. Using CSS Method 2:

using `flex:1` attribute like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7hA5/10/

more example for understanding flex:

http://jsfiddle.net/VgGbv/

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj5XB/1/)

This is your code slightly changed. (check question comments for hint).
I wrapped your containers in div:

```
<div class="container">
```

and this few changes added to css:

```
.container {background-color: white}
.image_container, .content {
    /* width: 50%;*/
    float: left;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
.content2 {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```